# SMS-lib: How to find the right settings to connect to IP modem?

Tags: java, smslib

I am using the [smslib](http://smslib.org/) library in java to connect a HSDPA dongle to my computer. I then use this dongle to send SMS messages.

Previously I used a USB modem; that I then mapped as a Serial port. I could connect to it as such:

```
gateway = new SerialModemGateway("SMSSERVER", 
                config.getProperty("COMPORT"),
                Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("BAUDRATE")), 
                config.getProperty("MANUFACTURER"), 
                config.getProperty("MODEL"));
```

And that would work. Now I have an IP Modem and I'm trying to connect to it the same way, using the IPModemGateway class:

```
gateway = new IPModemGateway("SMSSERVER",
                config.getProperty("IP"), 
                Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("IPPORT")), 
                config.getProperty("MANUFACTURER"), 
                config.getProperty("MODEL"));
```

From the smslib documentation I read:

> An IP Modem gateway is initialized like this:
>
> ```
> Modem gateway = new Modem("modem2", "192.168.1.100", "5000", "0000", "0000", "306942190000");
> ```

I am however not sure how I can find the port number (that is 5000 in the example).
The dongle I'm using is the Vodafone K5160. When I plug it in, it boots up as a local website on **192.168.9.100** (its default gateway) and when I check ipconfig the network adapter has an ip of **192.168.9.100**.

I assume I have to connect to 192.168.9.100, with a certain port. I can't get it to work.

I tried to use netstat -a:

```
TCP    192.168.9.100:139      D12WITA:0              LISTENING
TCP    192.168.9.100:58305    VodafoneMobile:http    TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.9.100:58311    VodafoneMobile:http    TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.9.100:58318    VodafoneMobile:http    TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.9.100:58349    VodafoneMobile:http    ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.9.100:58350    VodafoneMobile:http    TIME_WAIT
TCP    192.168.9.100:58358    VodafoneMobile:http    TIME_WAIT
```

But I'm not sure if this info is usable

Comment: Have you already tried all the ports from the netstat output?

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to deduce any valuable information or difference between the various ports -- although port 139 did take significantly longer before giving the error than the other ports